# Trying to replicate a figure using animate package

Tags: pdftex, animate, miktex2.9

I am trying to replicate animation in Figure 2. in [Grahn's pdf](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf). I am using animate package version 2019/01/23. I am compiling the LATEX file  `test.tex` to pdf using `pdflatex`. The input, output files together with **log file** can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i4o3mlxenu0regu/AADpn41-hTVTyrQY-wR0tgX5a?dl=0).

The problem is that after opening the output file *test.pdf* in *Adobe Acrobat Reader 19.010.20098*, the animation does not work. I am getting following error in Javascript debugger:
[image]

When I was using older version of `pdflatex` and `animate package`in 2018, everything was running without problems. Also back then I was using older version of Adobe Acrobat. The working pdf together with log file from 2018 can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2j5gzgb731bndrh/AADeGJQ9nEG37viH4DQL8r-ja?dl=0).

I do not know what exactly cause this problem (Javascript, newer version of animate package...). I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Compiles and runs without problems here; TexLive-2019-pretest, packages as of today. Could you please put `\listfiles` at the top of your input `*.tex` and then post the section below `*File List*` of the `*.log` file here?

Comment: And the same with up-to-date MiKTeX+packages. BTW, current `animate` version (CTAN/TL/MiKTeX) is `2019/03/06`.

Comment: Also, at the and of your log file I can read: `Package pdfbase Warning: Rerun to get internal references right!` and `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the reported problem is either caused by out-dated package versions or unresolved references that require another TeX run to be resolved.

Comment: @AlexG [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p6z86pjc57f7i7s/AADn86VDWyOpwlfWq6hTytzla?dl=0) is the `File List` log file

Comment: There are still warnings at the end of the log file that indicate the need for a second LaTeX run. Also, the packages are not current. Do a package update from within MiKTeX console.

Comment: @AlexG I rerun the program once again according to your suggestion and `Latex warning`. So far, I have not done package update yet but it works with the older version! Now the animation runs without problems. Thank you! I am little confused why it needed rerun to make it works, why it did not work at the first time/first run.

Comment: Virtually every LaTeX document needs at least two `latex` runs. This is required for resolving cross references, building the table of contents, bibliographies --- and animations ;-).

Comment: @AlexG Ahaa, I did not know about that :) Thank you again.